# How knockoutjs data binding works

Tags: knockout.js

see the code first and 
here is the jsfiddle link **http://jsfiddle.net/crtp0nzg/**

### html

```
<button id="button" data-bind="click: addRow">click</button>
<div id="dash" data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <div data-bind="text:$data"></div>
</div>
```

### js code

```
function TableModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Counter=1;
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([]),
    self.addRow = function() {
        self.rows.push( self.Counter+' '+ new Date() );
        self.Counter++;
        setTimeout(function()
        { 
            self.rows.shift(); 
            self.Counter--;
        }, 3000 + self.rows().length*1000 );
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new TableModel());
```

i like to know how **knockoutjs data binding works**

when user click first time on button then a single element is pushed in array and a single div is generated but when user click second time on button then again a single element is pushed in array and then also a one div is generated instead of 2. so my question is why always a single div is generated ?

when we click on button then a div is render and when second time click then another single div is render. so whenever button is click then always a single div is added in page but suppose when array has 5 element then also a single div is added in page.

how far i know that `foreach loop` should iterate as many as time the number of element in array. but in knockoutjs `foreach` always iterate one time and add or render a single div in page.

if anyone run my code then they can see when array has 5 element then knockoutjs foreach iterate one time only and add one new div in page.

it is getting very confusing for me how knockoutjs foreach works add html element in page.

how the below code is working and adding div in page not clear

```
<div id="dash" data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <div data-bind="text:$data"></div>
</div>
```

please help me to understand. thanks

Comment: The knockout foreach loop *does* iterate as many times as the number of elements in the array. Think of it this way: It always starts with an empty container. (In reality it remembers which elements it has created before and only creates the missing ones.)

Comment: thanks for reply. u said `(In reality it remembers which elements it has created before and only creates the missing ones` can u redirect me to any article which will describe the same what u have said with sample code regarding knockout data binding. thanks

Comment: Yes. Knockout is open source. Read the source code if you want to know how it does what it does.

Comment: Knockout source code would be huge. can u redirect me to any relevant article on this matter?

Comment: Can u plz stop writing txtspeak here? We are not on a chat. And I hate to say it, but I won't do the Googling for you. If you want to know how a piece of software works, read the source. If you want to know how to use it and what its features are, read the documentation or a few of the countless blog posts or stackoverflow answers. If you have a *real* question about it, ask it here. "How does this library work?" is not a real question.

Comment: Knockout is not binding your *changes* to the state but reflecting the *current* state of the model in your view. It will show, at any given time, the number of elements that exist in the array, not the history of changes.

Comment: @BrettGreen do not understand what u said properly.